# Alternative to wcsncpy_s

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode

I can only use this in Unicode, using the first argument as a TCHAR array. What should I do to convert to multibye?

I’m sort of long and have tried many things.

Comment: Avoid using C functions if possible. Use `std::wstring` or `CString` for Visual Studio. If your program is Unicode, then `TCHAR` is a macro for `wchar_t`. It's unclear what conversion you are trying to do and what it has to do with `wcsncpy_s`

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strncpy-s-strncpy-s-l-wcsncpy-s-wcsncpy-s-l-mbsncpy-s-mbsncpy-s-l), the charset-agnostic variant of `wcsncpy_s` is `_tcsncpy_s`. It's a macro that expands to `strncpy_s` in ANSI builds and to `wcsncpy_s` in Unicode builds.

Answer (score 0):

`wcsncpy_s()` deals with `wchar_t[]`, not `TCHAR[]`s.

`_tcsncpy_s()` deals with `TCHAR[]`.

`strncpy_s()` deals with `char[]`.

Anyway, are you sure you don't want to use `std::string`s instead?

Comment: Yes I’m doing some stuff with directs fonts